# Converting multiple rows into one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

| Index | ID | Year | Code | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 2018 | ABC | 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 100 | 2019 | DEF | 2 | 456 |
| 2 | 100 | 2019 | GHI | 3 | 789 |
| 3 | 100 | 2018 | JKL | 4 | 454 |
| 4 | 100 | 2019 | MNO | 5 | 678 |
| 5 | 100 | 2018 | PQR | 6 | 234 |
| 6 | 101 | 2019 | PQR | 3 | 234 |

and so on. I want to convert all the rows with the same ID into one column with their respective details.
In total, I have 1000 `ID`, 7 values for `Code`, 8 values for `Year` and 9 values for `Type`. I tried the same using `groupby` and `pivot` but couldn't land onto a successful solution.

I want my output as:

| Index | ID | Year1 | Code1 | Type1 | Value1 | Year2 | Code2 | Type2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 2018 | ABC | 1 | 123 | 2019 | DEF | 2 | 456 |

and so on,
i.e. all entries related to one ID in one row for different values of Year, Code, Type and Value.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
df2['cc'] = (df2.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
df2 = df2.pivot(index=['ID'], columns='cc', values=["Year", "Code","Type", "Value])
df2.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df2.columns]
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2578587, 4), indices imply (1,
> 4)

Comment: you need give example of expected output

Comment: Can you add expected ouput ans your code which failed?

Comment: df.groupby(['ID','Year','Code','Type']).sum() can it be the solution? If not please add an example of output so it can be easyer to work on it

Comment: I have to groupby using ID. So ideally all the entries related to one ID should be in one row.

Comment: I have added the required output and my trial code!!